# Xbox 360 Open Tray Error After Replacing Drive

Tags: xbox-360

I have an old (not slim) Xbox 360 Elite console.  Recently I started getting the "Open Tray" fault.  I tried all the suggestions online (tapping, opening up, cleaning, checking laser position) all to no avail.

I decided to get a replacement drive off eBay, knowing that if I got the same model I could either swap the old PCB into the new drive or failing that flash the new PCB with the key from the original one.

Original: Philips/Lite-on; Model: DG-16D2S; HW Ver: A0A1; FW Ver: 74850C
New: Philips/Lite-on; Model: DG-16D2S-09C; HW Ver: A0A2; FW Ver: 74850C

I've just tried putting the new drive in and was expecting it to read DVDs (not games until I swapped PCB or flashed), however I'm still getting the "Open Tray" fault.

It was my understanding that it should have played DVDs fine, is this correct?  I wanted to check before I open the new drive up in case I can return it.  Is it possible that the new drive has a fault already (it was listed as new not reconditioned); or do I have a bigger problem with my Xbox?

Many thanks.

Comment: I would have just gotten a replacement laser.  It's cheaper and you don't have to do any flashing.

Comment: I'm completely speculating here, but I'm pretty sure when you put a DVD into an Xbox it goes to the XBL home screen first.  Perhaps you need to flash it so that Xbox recognizes the drive?  Not sure at all, just something to consider.